# I Need a help to find missed pan locking knob to Rollei tripod

Tags: tripod

last year I lost the pan locking knob during my trip to the mountains and now I'm trying to find some spare parts. Please can someone give me advice on [image]where I can find it?

many thanks for any advice [image]

Comment: Is the ballhead assembly itself detachable from the rest of the tripod?

Comment: yes it is detachable

Comment: Not sure that should be the canonical answer, but if the ballhead is attached by a standard 3/8" or 5/8" thread, simply going for a whole new ballhead would be around $30 and is probably going to take less investment in time, shipping and research, esp given the existing ballhead already looks quite damaged, and the thread looks like it is in bad condition (which mighht be why the screw was lost in the first place...)